# DataTable not centering and not properly auto width

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

So I have a datatable inside a div, which is supposed to do the width setting and another one, which centers it:

```
<div style='text-align:center !important'>
    eakjflsdj
    <div id="ajax_table_header" style="width: 60%;">
        lbah
        <table id="ajax_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Reference</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Site</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The text centers as expected, but when I change
`<div id="ajax_table_header" style="width: 60%;">`
to
`<div id="ajax_table_header" style="width: auto;">`

It's as though no css was applied.

And when I `<table id="ajax_table" style="width: auto">` only the table is shrunk to its manageable size, while the search bar, pagination and everything else continues to stretch to the edge of the div.

What can I do to center and auto size it?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nc45tz0d/1/

**After much fiddling around `display: table` in `ajax_table_header` seemed to be the solution**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your div

```
<div id="ajax_table_header" style="width: 60%;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto">
```